# SELECT query not using pgvector (HNSW) index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, embedding, vector-database, pgvector

Given a table of about 1 mil. rows with columns `id` of type integer and `embedding` of type vector(2000), I ran the following query in pgAdmin query tool:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table USING hnsw (embedding vector_cosine_ops);
```

Whatever the SELECT query I ran after, I'm not seeing the index being used when prefixing the query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

After seeing @ankane's comments "[ordering by an expression [...] won't use the index](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/issues/216#issuecomment-1668244772)" and "[Postgres only supports ASC order index scans on operators](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/issues/216#issuecomment-1671959593)", I tried a simple `SELECT id, embedding <=> $1 FROM table` but it's still not using the index.

Many blog articles such as [this GCP one](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/faster-similarity-search-performance-with-pgvector-indexes) and [this other one](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/hnsw-indexes-with-postgres-and-pgvector) recommend to use `EXPLAIN` to check if the index is used.

Thus my following questions:

- How can I check that the index is actually built? With `EXPLAIN` I can see that even with the simplest query does not use the index, thus I'm even wondering if the index has actually been created (despite the `CREATE INDEX` having "returned successfully in 1 hr 6 min.")
- How to use the HNSW index with a `SELECT` statement?
- Assuming an index has been created, what happens if I rerun a `CREATE INDEX` statement? If I create an HNSW index, I assume it overwrites the existing index (is it?), does it overwrite if I create an `IVFFLAT` index instead?

Comment: I see no reason to think your simple query could or should use an index.  It looks like you started with something else, but then simplified it beyond the point of reason.  As you never showed us the query you **want** to run, it is hard to say how it could be modified to support an index.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue could be because you are not using ORDER BY with LIMIT.
Under the querying section there is this note...

Note: Combine with ORDER BY and LIMIT **to use an index**

[pgvector Querying Readme](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector?tab=readme-ov-file#querying)